# spree 2.0.3 heroku error precompiling assets "Error: Out of stack space"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

I'm trying to get a basic spree application working on Heroku.  I'm following http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html and the spree heroku guide.

I have edited `config/application.rb` to include `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
Then, because I need to precompile before I push to Heroku, I get stuck here:

```
D:\code\foo>rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Error: Out of stack space
  (in D:/code/foo/app/assets/javascripts/admin/all.js)
d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
...much more...
```

The all.js asset is unchanged from the original installation:

Running

```
rake assets:clean
```

before the precompile fixed this for somebody else, but not for me.

Browsing around it looks like this might be a windows specific issue?  If it matters I used railsinstaller and I'm running Windows 7 on fairly new laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then, because I need to precompile before I push to Heroku

This is false.  By default, Heroku's Cedar stack compiles your assets during slug compilation when you push to Heroku.

For more information see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline